# Exit from a Login Form into iFrame

Tags: jsf, iframe, primefaces

JSF2, Primefaces 5.0

I have a website with a login form (user and password).
I need to put the same login form in a another website, and i did think to use an iframe.. 
But with this solution, I remain inside the iframe...

Is there a method (or a PF component) which can resolve this (to exit from iframe and show my website) ?

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to leave focus of the iframe and restore focus to the parent frame? Porthole.js can be utilized for childframes to send messages back to the parent frame.

Comment: no.. i mean to leave the iframe and show the full page (that is the page that currently appear erroneously into the iframe) when i click on the button "login".